LoadingSpinner Tapestry
Hello dear community,
I am in the process of adding a LoadingSpinner with Tapestry5. However, I can't get the LoadingSpinner to run on the click event. I can show/hide the LoadingSpinner via the browser console, but my browser does not respond to the Javascript onClick command when I click on the event link. I have also tried to switch to JQuery but unfortunately in vain. When executing the method manually, everything works perfectly. Hiding via the callback works perfectly.
Does anyone know what the problem could be? How can I execute the method loadSpinner(1) when executing the event link?
<a t:type="eventlink" t:zone="appMaintenanceZone" name="reindexArticle" event="reindexArticle" onclick="showSpinner(0)">Update</a>

<t:zone t:id="appMaintenanceZone" id="appMaintenanceZone" t:update="show">

@OnEvent("reindexArticle")
    void reindexAricle()
    {
        if (request.isXHR()) {

            //TODO: execute $('#loadSpinnerDiv1').show(); on appMaintenanceZone

            articleService.reindex();
            
            ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender("appMaintenanceZone", appMaintenanceZone)
                .addCallback((JavaScriptCallback) javascriptSupport -> {
                    javascriptSupport.addScript("$('#loadSpinnerDiv1').hide();");
                });
        }
    }
</t:zone>


Note: Not an exact answer to your question but a suggestion to use a Tapestry built-in component to get a loading spinner in a very convenient way.
Use the ProgressiveDisplay component
Use ProgressiveDisplay.
It's included in the Tapestry core component library, hence available out-of-the box.
Example:
<t:ProgressiveDisplay>
    Component body including perhaps
    <t:AnotherComponentThatTakesAWhileToRender/>
    and perhaps even another (nested)
    <t:ProgressiveDisplay>
        more content here
    </t:ProgressiveDisplay>
</t:ProgressiveDisplay>

As an alternative to specifying a component body you can create the result programmatically by handling the event fired by the ProgressiveDisplay component.
@OnEvent(EventConstants.PROGRESSIVE_DISPLAY)
Block onProgressiveDisplay() {
    return new RenderableAsBlock(new StringRenderable("Hello, world."));
}

Changing the default label / spinner style
If you don't like the Tapestry default label ("Loading...") you can specify something else with the initial parameter.
Examples:
<t:ProgressiveDisplay initial="Calculating...">
</t:ProgressiveDisplay>

<t:ProgressiveDisplay initial="message:spinner-label">
</t:ProgressiveDisplay>

<t:ProgressiveDisplay initial="block:fancy">
</t:ProgressiveDisplay>

<t:block t:id="fancy">
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 spinner component (by example) -->
    <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
</t:block>

